# dbo.__RefactorLog Table not being included in bacpac file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have a database that I created and am modifying through a sqlproj. As a result the database schema has a dbo.__RefactorLog table.
When I export a bacpac file from the database, everything in the schema is included except the __RefactorLog table.

Is this the expected behaviour ? 
Is there a way I can get the __RefactorLog table to be included in the bacpac ?

Comment: OK, tried several ways to reproduce this - including forcing the __RefactorLog to be extracted using the parameter for SQLPackage to export all tables and a single named table. When I tried to force __RefactorLog, I was told it didn't exist in the existing schema. The 2014 SSMS GUI shows it, but my DBs have cross-DB references so that extract failed.  From what I can tell, this seems to be expected behavior. SSDT should create and populate this table as needed when you publish, but you'll need the appropriate rights granted to do so. For your scenario, script and push manually once?

Comment: @PeterSchott, yes this is pretty much what I'm getting - in the case where when I only select the __RefactorLog table for the bacpac it tells me the table doesn't exist. I'm presuming there is some 'setting' on the table that is causing this behaviour (possibly due to its creation via the `sp_addextendedproperty`) ? My problem is that for the publish script to run properly I need the __RefactorLog table to exist in the database - so when I try to test the script on a copy of the database it fails because the bacpac the copy is generated from doesn't have the __ReefactorLog table.

Comment: Try gen'ing a script against your local machine and capture that script to see how it creates the RefactorLog table. You can have that script run against your other servers to the table will exist when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

The __RefactorLog table is essentially a 'system'/internal table automatically generated by SSDT. SSDT uses it to keep a record of what Refactor operations it has already carried out during deploys i.e. should it refactor that column or table again.

The table doesn't need to be part of the schema, and will be recreated automatically when needed on the destination systems.

If you are wondering why it doesn't automatically generate the table straight away, it will only do it when there is a Refactor operation SSDT needs to complete and therefore record as complete. Therefore a 'fresh' copy of the schema will not have a Refactor table created.

**Short verson:** it's an internal table, no it shouldn't be there, what you're seeing sounds normal to me.

For more information about Refactor operations / what they are, see [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272704(v=vs.103).aspx).

Comment: thanks @hanzworld. Our issue is that a trial run of a schema update on a copy of a production db isn't valid because the lack of a refactorlog table (with all the 'to date' refactorings) results in different outcome/actions.

Comment: @paul.dev Hmm, refactorlog tables don't quite work that way (cause and effect is the wrong way around - they get generated after a refactor as a log of what _has_ been done, not 'to do'. Todo refactors are stored in the .refactorlog file as part of SSDT). Can you post more information regarding your schema, your SSDT schema and the script you get (and what's wrong with it) as I'd be keen to help figure out where it's going wrong?

Comment: I disagree that they're not needed. If you use SSDT to publish a db to version 1, then export/import via a .bacpac to a different server, then use SSDT to publish to v2 you may encounter problems because the `__refactorLog` table isn't there. The history of any refactor operations that were applied in v1 are lost and SSDT may try to re-apply them.

Comment: @Rory fair example where the lack of RefactorLog table would cause an issue. In my opinion (based on experience only) it feels more like a scenario which SSDT doesn't actually cater for / would break in (there are plenty of others too!) as opposed to something not behaving as designed. Certainly what's outlined above is the behaviour 'out of the box' which I agree doesn't work in your scenario. Might be worth [submitting to the SSDT team](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback) as a suggested enhancement/bug?

Comment: Sidenote: I'm not 100% sure but I'm starting to think this might be because __RefactorLog is declared as a system table in the database.

Comment: @hanzworld I'll try changing it to not be a system table and then see if it works. I still think it's wrong to not include this table in a .bacpac, but perhaps it's because it's wrong of SSDT to declare __RefactorLog as a system table rather than wrong of the .bacpac creation process to not include system tables.

Comment: @hanzworld - I tried an Export to .bacpac and then Import from .bacpac when dbo.__RefactorLog was NOT a system table and it WAS successfully imported. I don't think anyone changed whether it was flagged as a system table though ... so I'm wondering if either a) an update to SSDT has fixed this so it's not a system table anymore, or b) when it's deployed to Azure SQL Database it's not flagged as a system table. In my case I exported the bacpac from an Azure SQL Database. I notice in my local dbs the __RefactorLog table is always a system table but in Azure it's not a system table.

Answer (score 0):

This might be intended behaviour, however it will become a problem if you have new entries in your refactor log and want to apply then next time you publish to a database restored from a bacpac.

To include dbo.__RefactorLog in your bacpac, simply remove the extended property *microsoft_database_tools_support* on the table using either method:

- Using Management Studio (right-click table -> properties -> extended properties -> select property and click delete).
- Using stored procedure `EXEC sp_dropextendedproperty  N'microsoft_database_tools_support', N'schema', N'dbo', N'table', N'__RefactorLog'`

(Don't know if this has any side-effects, but nothing we have experienced)

We used the second approach in a post-deployment script in our SSDT project.